# AOP - cancel or following execution from advice

Tags: java, kotlin, aop, spring-aop

I am writing an annotation that should perform some validations on MessageId before execute the function.

```
@Aspect
@Component
class ValidatorAspect {
    @Before("@annotation(whatever.Validator)")
    fun checkMessage(joinPoint: JoinPoint) {
        val messageId = joinPoint.args[1] as String
        // run some validations
        // if any validation fails, this should stop execution
        // and annotated function not be called
    }
}
```

And my function is annotated with:

```
    @Validator
    @SqsListener("myqueue")
    fun run(message: String) {
         // code to proccess message
    }
```

The order is being called correctly: first SqsListener receive message then my validator should be executed before annotated function.

How can I force a stop execution from `run()`? If any validation fail, I don't want that annotated class be called - also, I don't want to throw an exception, I'm looking for something smooth, just stop, no exceptions :)

I have tried to use `@Around` but my Advice was being called after my function `run()`

Any ideas or suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

In `@Before`, you have no other choice than to throw an exception if you want to stop the program from entering the intercepted method. Apparently, you want to avoid throwing an exception, so `@Around` is the advice type you want to use here.

> I have tried to use `@Around` but my advice was being called after my function `run()`

With all due respect, that is impossible. You get access to the joinpoint before it is called, that is how it works. Maybe you accidentally called `joinpoint.proceed()` before doing the validation. Of course, you have to do it the other way around, first validating and then deciding if you want to proceed or just return an alternative result without proceeding.